# Video not playing in IE in hidden div using JW Player, SWFObject and FancyZoom

Tags: javascript, flash, video, swfobject, jwplayer

I have a video that is meant to start playing when a user clicks on an image and said image opens a FancyZoom overlay. It works fine in every browser except IEs. If I place the video in a div that is not hidden (display:none actually), the video starts as expected. So it seems there is a problem with either Flash, JW Player, SWFObject or any combination of these when trying to load a video in a hidden div.

Anyone know any workarounds? I tried modifying the FancyZoom library (see my fork: http://github.com/lgomez/fancy-zoom/blob/master/prototype/js/fancyzoom.js) so I could use a callback to inject the video AFTER the zoom effect was completed but that did'n work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not whetted to FancyZoom, I'd recommend using [JW Box](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/21/jw-box-the-jw-player-lightbox). It was designed for precisely this purpose. Additionally, you can edit the CSS so that it looks a bit more like FancyZoom, if you prefer that look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with this issue as well.

This seems to be an issue with swfobject or flash from what I can find on google.  The issue arrises when the flash you are loading loads into a div that has a style of `display:none`.  When that div is toggled to `display:block` the div appears blank.  No one seems to have a good answer as to why this happens or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support SWF playback when hiding the SWF.  Some browsers will not play the SWF if CSS is used to hide it, and the SWF will sometimes reload (go to frame 1) when un-hidden. The behavior isn't reliable cross-browser.